# Google Sheet setvalues is not a function error

Tags: google-apps-script

Good day Team,

I have created a simple data entry sheet, the clear function works fine but my SubmitData part is not working and is giving me an error "TypeError: dataS.getRange(...).setvalues is not a function" Any help with this would be appreciated. Thank you

My code is below

```
// Clear Form
function ClearCell() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var fromS = ss.getSheetByName("From"); //From Sheet

var rangesToClear = ["Q6", "R6", "S6", "T6"];
for (var i=0; i<rangesToClear.length; i++) {
  fromS.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent();
}
}
//------------------------------------------------------
//Input Values
function SubmitData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var fromS = ss.getSheetByName("From"); //Date entry Sheet
  var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); //Data Sheet

  var values = [[fromS.getRange("Q6").getValue(),
                 fromS.getRange("R6").getValue(),
                 fromS.getRange("S6").getValue(),
                 fromS.getRange("T6").getValue()]];
dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow()+1,1,1,4).setvalues(values);
ClearCell();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, based on your error `"is not a function"`, it means that your function is not valid. Upon seeing your code, you've got a typo there. Use `setValues()` instead of `setvalues()`

See: [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

#### EDIT:

- I have optimized your code below. See the difference

```
// Clear Form
function ClearCell() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var fromS = ss.getSheetByName("From"); //From Sheet
  // Clear Q6 - T6 
  // Avoid loop if not necessary, it will slow down your run time and waste resources
  fromS.getRange(6,17,1,4).clearContent();
}
//------------------------------------------------------
//Input Values
function SubmitData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var fromS = ss.getSheetByName("From"); //Date entry Sheet
  var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); //Data Sheet
  // Get Q6 - T6 values
  // Minimize the number of calls you are doing by optimizing your method calls. 
  var values = fromS.getRange(6,17,1,4).getValues();
  dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow()+1,1,1,4).setValues(values);
  ClearCell();
}
```

Comment: Well that was easy... I'm so sorry I should of checked the code/spelling before posting.

Now that I fixed it ran fine but there was no output on Sheet "Date" in cells A2 to D2 would you know why this is?

Comment: You are writing on `Data` not `Date` Sheet. it should be added on the last row of that sheet. tested your script and it shows there. Maybe you are looking at the wrong sheet

Comment: Or maybe, if you already ran it multiple times, it was already deleted by `ClearCell`. Make sure to have `Q6`-`T6` populated before running your `SubmitData`

Comment: I have improved your script above by editing my answer. Kindly check @AlenBaltic